# Why does Shakespeare let two or more actors finish a pentameter?

Tags: terminology, shakespeare, syllables, meter

To complete the number of syllables in a pentameter Shakespeare (and other contemporaries) let multiple actors say a verse, like shown in Macbeth

Were two actors complete a pentameter:

> DUNCAN: As seemeth by his plight, of the revolt
>
> The newest state
>
> MALCOLM: This is the seargent
>
> Who like a good and hardy soldier fought

Or sometimes three actors:

> ROSS: The victory fell on us
>
> DUNCAN: Great happiness!
>
> ROSS: That now
>
> Sweno, the Norway's king, craves composition

I was wondering if **anyone knew how this technique is called**. Also, I know there's a practical reason for doing this but **would there also be a stylistic one?**. Source any stylistic motives please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as being far more appropriate to another site in the Stack Exchange network, LiteratureSE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Terminology about poetry (like terminology about arguments/biases/fallacies) has been on topic herein the past though I agree that literature.SE would be more likely to know.

Comment: @Mitch The tags selected do not include 'terminology', and at least half the question (90%+ of the answers) will be  discussing style.

Comment: What, not how! Isn’t that one of the first things taught in English as a Foreign Language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In literary criticism, such lines are often called **short lines**. For example, see [Bowers](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40372177), 1980):

> Because of its abrupt break with regularity, the **Shakespearean short line** within a pentameter speech is immediately noticed by the ear and, in a reading edition, by the eye.

[Sicherman](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2869926) (1984) also uses **short lines** as well as **part-lines**. She argues that many (though not all) of the short lines in Shakespeare plays have a stylistic effect (put in italics), and she uses *Julius Caesar* as evidence:

> Using the example of *Julius Caesar*, widely considered the best printed of the Folio texts and therefore not so susceptible to editorial tampering, I shall try to show that the Folio **short lines** often *provide eloquent implicit directions for stage-business, rhetorical emphases, and - above all - nuances of characterization*.

This terminology also appears in more popular sources, like public-facing websites ([Elizabethan Drama](http://elizabethandrama.org/primers/understanding-iambic-pentameter/)):

> 4. Using **Short Lines**. Finally, an individual line may just simply fall well short of 10-syllables for no obvious reason at all. A speech may end with a short line, for example with only 4 or 5 syllables; this is followed by a different character speaking the next line, that line containing its full complement of 10 syllables. This technique can be used to signal that the speakers are about to change topics or ideas.

Comment: 'The Greeks had a word for it or something rather like it.  Greek tradedy was written in iambic trimeter (three iambic feet, where the base iambic foot is four syllables) and so in tudor terms in iambic hexameters of six feet, not the tudor five.  Emotionally excited dialogue could be used to 'raise the temperature':  this was done by giving alternate lines to two disputing characters.  It was called 'stichomythia' ('speech in ranks').  When it gets really hot you get split lines ('hemistichs')!  But this is different and TeliesinMerlin has the answer.